# Xamarin: How to Display Menu Button in MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

MasterDetailPage in Xamarin has no Menu Button at upper left of the screen when launched from other page

[image]

code is:

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BackBtn_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        private void LoginBtn_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EmployeeDashboard());
        }
    }
```

But when launched from App, there is Menu Button

[image]

code is

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new EmployeeDashboard());
        }
```

I need to display the menu buttons of the MasterDetailPage (EmployeeDashboard) from LoginBtn_OnClicked event.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add your page in masterdetailpage and call masterdetailpage in login button click

Comment: Please provide some code example or more description to so that others can understand your answer easily